# How can I get ACF field value in WordPress loop?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I'm trying to get ACF filed value for post in loop. But for some reason the value is not being displayed.

I've already tried

```
<?php $field = get_field('field_name'); echo $field;  ?>
```

And

```
<?php the_field('field_name', $post->ID); ?>
```

None of the methods are working. See the loop code below:

```
<?php 
    $args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="col-sm-6">

        <h2 class="the-title"><?php the_field('field_name', $post->ID); ?> +  <?php the_title() ;?> </h2>


    </div>

<?php endwhile; else: ?> Nothing here <?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

How can I get the ACF field values in loop?

Answer (score 5):

Try use

```
the_field('field_name', get_the_ID());
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't closed the array correctly.Please try this

```
<?php 
        $args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => 4
       );
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    ?>
    <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="col-sm-6">

            <h2 class="the-title"><?php the_field('field_name', $post->ID); ?> +  <?php the_title() ;?> </h2>


        </div>

    <?php endwhile; else: ?> Nothing here <?php endif; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax error in your code. Specifically, you are trying to assign a value to the $the_query variable inside the $args array, which is not allowed.

To fix the issue, you need to create the WP_Query object before you define the $args array. Here's a corrected version of your code:

```
<?php 
    $args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => 4
    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h2 class="the-title"><?php the_field('field_name', $post->ID); ?> + <?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; else: ?> 
    <p>Nothing here</p>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

In this corrected code, the WP_Query object is created before the $args array is defined, and the $the_query variable is assigned the value of the WP_Query object. The rest of the code should function as expected.